# What to do when I posted a question that fits other site, but my flag asking to migrate is not being handled?

Tags: discussion, migration

I posted a question two days ago which did not fit to [the Interpersonal Skills Stack Exchange site](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/6303/how-is-this-rhetoric-ploy-called), and I requested moderator intervention for moving it to the [Philosophy Stack Exchange site](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) (like suggested in a comment) yesterday. However, this did not happen so far, and I do not want to duplicate this post to the Philosophy Stack Exchange site.

What possibilities do I have as a user if no moderator reacts?

Comment: You have no answers. Delete the post and repost it somewhere it fits.

Comment: Please don't make it sound as the moderators are to blame. It does not sound good, and always a bad idea to point fingers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer your general question -

Your IPS question has no answers so there's nothing preventing you from taking this into your own hands. If you want it moved, you are capable of doing so yourself by deleting the post on IPS and posting it anew on Philosophy. As such, there's no reason to request that the IPS moderators (of which I am one) migrate it or for you to wait for a response to your flag.  While it is generally not recommended to ask identical questions on multiple sites, it's perfectly acceptable to remove the question from one site and ask it on a different one, particularly if it's been closed.

With so many sites on the network, it is understandably sometimes quite difficult to get the right site the first time.

---

To address the flag specifically -

Your flag has been handled.

I declined your flag because we were unable to ascertain whether the question is on topic on Philosophy or not. If it's closed there after being migrated, it will be bounced back to IPS rather than being put on hold so that you can improve it. This helps no one. If you ask it locally on Philosophy, if they need to, they can close it and give you guidance on how to improve it.

Please remember that the moderators are volunteers and it was the weekend.

In future, if you have questions about IPS specifically, feel free to ask in chat or on the [IPS child meta](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Migration is... one of those things. While there's standard migration paths, migration to and from beta sites is pretty uncommon. In addition, for a good migration, you really want someone who knows both sites and can decide if a question is worth migrating

Self deletion and reasking the question's probably the least troublesome route. Probably won't help if its closed there for whatever reason though.